# Algorithms for alignment of posets

Tags: bipartite-matching, assignment-problem

I have been looking for a while but I cannot find an algorithm for a particular generalisation of sequence alignment.

I have two posets $(A, <)$ and $(B, <)$ and a similarity score $s(a, b)$ for all $a \in A, b \in B$. I wish to find a maximal scoring alignment such that both partial orders are respected.

An alignment is a poset $(AB, <)$ of $(a, b)$ pairs such that any $a \in A$ or $b \in B$ should be in at most one pair in $AB$. We say $AB$ respects the orders of $A$ and $B$ if for all $(a, b), (a', b') \in AB$ then $(a, b) < (a', b')$ if and only if $a < a'$ and $b < b'$.

The score of the alignment is just the sum of the scores of the pairs.
$$
s(AB) = \sum_{(a,b) \in AB} s(a, b)
$$

In standard sequence alignment, both sequences are totally ordered (by their linear representation), in my case I only have a partial order. If it helps, this partial order is defined by each element's location in a planar graph.

I did find [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11786-020-00496-8) that discusses these issues but I don't think it supplies an algorithm. It does suggest such an algorithm is possible.

This also seems related to the problem of bipartite graph matching (c.f. [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)) but those algorithms do not consider order respecting constraints.

The [Euclidean bipartite matching problem](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall08/cps234/projects/sayan_proj.pdf) also seems related but whilst my nodes $a, b$ live in Euclidean space, their similarity scores $s(a, b)$ are not a (simple) function of their location.

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly, the solution Is the straightforward generalization of dynamic programming solution for sequence alignment. For each pair $a$, $b$, find the sequences with maximum similarity which end by $a$ and $b$. There are $n^2$ states, each requires $n^2$ Time to compute (using precomputed results for smaller pairs) and the running time will be $n^4$,

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Dmitry. I think I may have mistated the question however. I think my alignment should be a poset not a sequence. Let me think about it and then I'll update the question.

Comment: I'm wondering whether the revised problem formulation correctly captures what you want.  The score of a poset $(AB,<)$ does not depend on the relation $<$.   Therefore, the following poset is a solution: match each $a$ to a $b$ to maximize the total score (an instance of maximum bipartite matching), then let $<$ be the empty relation (i.e., all pairs in $AB$ are incomparable).  This seems too trivial so I wonder whether some requirements might be missing.  If this meets your requirements, I can write this as an answer.

Comment: That's a good point. Sounds like I need to make sure the order is respected in both directions. Will edit the question.

Comment: I think the current definition also doesn't put any restrictions on $AB$. You again can make any assignments you want. After that, simply define $<$ on $AB$ so that it satisfies your condition.